# Allow a process to stop another process for a given time c

Tags: c, linux, signals

I want to know if there is a way to make a parent process stop his child for a given time using `signal`
for example:

```
pid_t pid = fork();

if(pid==0){
  while(1){

//some code here

  }
}else{

// some code to make child process stop for x seconds

}
```

Comment: You may always arm a SIGUSR1 handler that calls the `alarm(N)` function to arrange for a SIGALRM signal to be delivered to the calling process in N seconds and then invoke `pause` if you want to stop a process for a time that is in the order of the seconds...but be careful that signals are not immediately handled at the recipient when they are raised by a sender process, rather they undergo to the timing according to which the OS performs certain activities and which can introduces additional delays (anyhow small when compared to seconds).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use SIGSTOP and SIGCONT to stop and continue the process. In combination with some time delay function (e.g. sleep() ) you may get the desired effect.

You may check the example here: https://ostechnix.com/suspend-process-resume-later-linux/